# my code works in tomcat but in websphere no?

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces, websphere, websphere-8

I'm trying the below code in my controller to redirect to login.jsf page:

```
try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .redirect(req.getContextPath() + "/view/auth/login.jsf");
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
                        
this code works in tomcat but in websphere i get this error:

javax.el.ELException: /view/templates/header.xhtml @13,76 rendered="#{not empty authController.userVO and authController.authenticated}": Error reading 'userVO' on type com.metier.controller.authentification.AuthController
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'userVO' on type com.metier.controller.authentification.AuthController
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendRedirectWithStatusCode(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:577) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendRedirect(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:534) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at
```

please any help.

Comment: please any help

Comment: Just going off the first part of the error... What does authController look like? Does it have userVO as a variable and a proper setter method?